# How to save a list of lists in R?

Tags: r, rvest

I stored in a list a number of web pages I collected with `rvest::read_html`. Now I would like to save this big list of web pages for later use (so that I don't have to scrape the data again).

I tried `saveRDS`, but the resulting file is only 1kb and reading the data back results in a crash. I suspect that the dynamic nature of the object I'm trying to save gets in the way.

What would be the best way to save my data?
Many thanks in advance for you help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. To get the best answers, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the code that results in the problem.

Comment: write.csv(list.df, file = "newfile.csv")

Comment: You might try `save`, though `saveRDS` should work for saving a single object.

Comment: @theArun : thank you, but the object I'm trying to save is not a dataframe but a list (that contains lists)

Comment: @lmo : thanks! I tried both saveRDS and save, they both produce a tiny file that doesn't contain the list I'm trying to save

Comment: can you provide the list you are trying to save? it should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: If you want to download the website and parse/use it later you could also download it via: `httr::GET("URL YOU WANT TO DOWNLOAD", write_disk("YOUR LOCAL PATH", overwrite = FALSE))` and lateron read it into R via `read_html("YOUR LOCAL PATH")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the text as a corpus of text and write them. The easiest is from package tm in R. Check this https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/tm.pdf for more details.